# How to remove invalid characters from an xml file using sed or Perl

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I want to get rid of all invalid characters; example `hexadecimal value 0x1A` from an XML file using sed.
What is the regex and the command line? 
EDIT
Added Perl tag hoping to get more responses. I prefer a one-liner solution.
EDIT
These are the valid XML characters

```
x9 | xA | xD | [x20-xD7FF] | [xE000-xFFFD] | [x10000-x10FFFF]
```

Comment: such as?  that's a pretty broad statement.  clarify

Comment: @KevinDTimm I mean `0x1A` is an example of hexadecimal character that I want to remove from my xml file

Comment: You mean like the 1Ah as eof-marker in stone age? Better use tr for this.

Comment: In the general case, sed is the wrong tool for this. A similar script in Perl is easy to make; `perl -pi -e 'y/\x1a//d' file.xml`

Comment: @tripleee I was looking for a one-liner solution but I guess Perl can do it. I will modify my question and re-tag accordingly. Your example does not remove all non-valid characters by the way

Comment: Valid chars: `#x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]`

Comment: @ ikegami Do you mind if I include your list of valid chars in the question? It may assist people who know regex but not too familiar with XML spec

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming UTF-8 XML documents:

```
perl -CSDA -pe'
   s/[^\x9\xA\xD\x20-\x{D7FF}\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}]+//g;
' file.xml > file_fixed.xml
```

If you want to encode the bad bytes instead,

```
perl -CSDA -pe'
   s/([^\x9\xA\xD\x20-\x{D7FF}\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}])/
      "&#".ord($1).";"
   /xeg;
' file.xml > file_fixed.xml
```

You can call it a few different ways:

```
perl -CSDA     -pe'...' file.xml > file_fixed.xml
perl -CSDA -i~ -pe'...' file.xml     # Inplace with backup
perl -CSDA -i  -pe'...' file.xml     # Inplace without backup
```

Comment: Using the second version I am getting an error `Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 1.`. I did a copy paste and removed new lines.

Comment: @user841550, Fixed. I'm not sure if the bytes are allowed in the encoded form, but I put it out there in case you wanted to try. Newlines don't need to be removed, btw.

Comment: This is a great solution. A tiny edge case where this fails (OOM): A large file containing just a single line.

Comment: Re "*If you want to encode the bad bytes instead*", Is that legal?

Answer (score 3):

The `tr` command would be simpler. So, try something like:

```
cat <filename> | tr -d '\032' > <newfilename>
```

Note that ascii character '0x1a' has the octal value '032', so we use that instead with `tr`. Not sure if `tr` likes hex.

Comment: This worked 100%, when none of the other solutions (including using iconv) worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
perl -pi -e 's/[^\x9\xA\xD\x20-\x{d7ff}\x{e000}-\x{fffd}\x{10000}-\x{10ffff}]//g' file.xml
```

Comment: You're matching bytes against values that would never fit into bytes.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a way to do this with sed, like so:

```
cat input_file | LANG=C sed -E \
   -e 's/.*/& /g' \
   -e 's/(('\
'[\x9\xa\xd\x20-\x7f]|'\
'[\xc0-\xdf][\x80-\xbf]|'\
'[\xe0-\xec][\x80-\xbf][\x80-\xbf]|'\
'[\xed][\x80-\x9f][\x80-\xbf]|'\
'[\xee-\xef][\x80-\xbf][\x80-\xbf]|'\
'[\xf0][\x80-\x8f][\x80-\xbf][\x80-\xbf]'\
')*)./\1?/g' \
   -e 's/(.*)\?/\1/g' \
   -e 's|]]>|]]>]]<![CDATA[>|g' > output_file
```

This works in four steps:

1. Add a single whitespace character to the end of every line.
2. Replace every sequence of legal characters followed by any character
   with the same sequence of legal characters followed by a question mark
   character (instead of the any).
   Note that in a line of only legal characters, the '.' matches the last
   character in the line, which is why we added a space in step 1.
3. Remove the last character in the line, which we expect to be a question mark.
4. Replace the string ']]>' with ']]>]]'.

The LANG=C env variable is set to prevent sed from doing charset conversion itself - it should treat every character as 8-bit ascii.